# Non-deterministic behavior of TensorFlow while_loop()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have implemented an algorithm using TensorFlow `while_loop` with large matrices and I have recently noticed strange behavior: I am getting different results with different runs, sometimes even `nan` values. I have spend some time on narrowing down the problem and I now have the following minimal example. I  take a large matrix K of size `15000x15000` filled with ones, and then calculate K⁵u for the vector u filled with ones. After one iteration, I expect as result the vector filled with `15000`. But this is not what happens.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

n = 15000
np_kernel_mat = np.ones((n, n), dtype=np.float32)
kernel_mat = tf.constant(np_kernel_mat)

# for debugging
def compare_kernel(kernel_matrix):
    print("AverageDifference:" + str(np.average(np.abs(np_kernel_mat - kernel_matrix))))
    print("AmountDifferent:" + str(np.count_nonzero(np.abs(np_kernel_mat - kernel_matrix))))
    return True

# body of the loop
def iterate(i, u):
    # for debugging
    with tf.control_dependencies(tf.py_func(compare_kernel, [kernel_mat], [tf.bool])):
        u = tf.identity(u)
    # multiply
    u = tf.matmul(kernel_mat, u)
    # check result and kernel 
    u = tf.Print(u, [tf.count_nonzero(tf.abs(kernel_mat-np_kernel_mat))], "AmountDifferentKernel: ")
    u = tf.Print(u, [tf.count_nonzero(tf.abs(u-float(n)))], "AmountDifferentRes: ")
    i = i + 1
    return i, u


def cond(i, u):
    return tf.less(i, 5)

u0 = tf.fill((n, 1), 1.0, name='u0')
iu_0 = (tf.constant(0), u0)
iu_final = tf.while_loop(cond, iterate, iu_0, back_prop=False, parallel_iterations=1)
u_res = iu_final[1]


with tf.Session() as sess:
    kernel_mat_eval, u_res_eval = sess.run([kernel_mat, u_res])
    print(np.array_equal(kernel_mat_eval, np_kernel_mat))
```

Now running this I get the following output:

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:898] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX TITAN X major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.076
pciBusID: 0000:00:0f.0
totalMemory: 11.93GiB freeMemory: 11.81GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 11435 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:00:0f.0, compute capability: 5.2)
minimal_example.py:25: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtr[8/281]
  print("AverageDifference:" + str(np.average(np.abs(np_kernel_mat - kernel_matr
ix))))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:70: RuntimeWarning
: overflow encountered in reduce
  ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
AverageDifference:nan
minimal_example.py:26: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  print("AmountDifferent:" + str(np.count_nonzero(np.abs(np_kernel_mat - kernel_
matrix))))
AmountDifferent:4096
AmountDifferentKernel: [0]
AmountDifferentRes, DifferenceRes: [4][inf]
AverageDifference:nan
AmountDifferent:4096
AmountDifferentKernel: [0]
AmountDifferentRes, DifferenceRes: [15000][nan]
AverageDifference:nan
AmountDifferent:4096
AmountDifferentKernel: [0]
AmountDifferentRes, DifferenceRes: [15000][nan]
AverageDifference:nan
...
```

It is clear that in the second iteration, the result is not `15000` anymore, but that doesn't explain why the difference is nan. On CPU, everything works fine (the difference is then something like `2e08`).

Now my questions are:
Why is the output of the Print op different to the output of the `py_func` print? Why is the evaluation of the matrix again equal to the original matrix? Why do I get different results over different runs? Can someone reproduce this?

I am running this on `Ubuntu 16.04`, `TensorFlow 1.8`, `numpy 1.14`, `python3.6`.
GPU is GeForceGTX 1080.

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.48  Thu Mar 22 00:42:57 PDT 2018
GCC 
version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)
```

Comment: Just to drop by and say that this is a really well posed question. Thanks for taking the time to produce it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results on TF 1.10.1 running on a GTX 1080 Ti (Ubuntu, python 3.6).

Comment: Neither can I with TF 1.8 (same environment).

Comment: I have updated to TF 1.10 and the problem seems to have disappeared: however, I still get large deviations from the expected result for large matrices (I changed the example to compare the result against the actual expected result of n^(i+1)).

Comment: @LiaFiona Can you give some more detail about what is currently the issue and what you were expecting to get? I have run the snippet in CPU and GPU with TF 1.10 and I get the same results in both cases (I am on Windows, Py 3.6 and a Titan V, though...).

Comment: @jdehesa I have created a paste with a slightly modified example: https://pastebin.com/fUJfMiLR The issue is that the difference in the last result is now 1.2666374e+15, but as far as my maths is correct there shouldn't be any difference. Would be nice to confirm that others have this issue too.

Comment: @LiaFiona Okay I can see that behavior now, both with GPU and CPU. It is definitely a precision problem, switching to `float64` reduces it a lot. Note that the numbers you are computing in the last iteration are about 7.6×10²⁰, so an error of 1.3×10¹⁵ is "relatively small" (`float32` is typically precise to about 7 decimal positions, but I guess the error accumulates through the iterations).

Comment: you should use the quantum python library.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your problem is stemming from seeding issues, make sure that you set a seed for both `random.seed()`, and for `numpy.random.seed()`. You'll need to seed both, as numpy's random seed is independent from the `random` random state.